# Windows shared folder access issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

I have a file server. It has user Jes with full administrative privileges. Server has shared readonly folder "publish". Everyone can read from it. User Jes can do with it everything.

Password protected sharing on server is off.

I'm try to access shared folder "Publish" on server and I receive message: "access denied".

Solution that I use is to "map network device" to folder "Publish" with Jes credentials. Sometimes it work, but sometimes I need about 10 times reboot to make it work!

This is a very furious.

I'm just want to normal access server shared folder with Jes credentials. How can I do this?

Comment: Is this on a domain? Is there local accounts along with domain accounts assigned permissions? Are there NTFS permissions on the directory in question?

Comment: It is local network.

Comment: That doesn't really answer any of my questions..

Comment: Domain accounts don exists, only server and my local computer.

Comment: NTFS permissions is read for everyone and full acces for user Jes

Comment: There is no Domain, only standart windows LAN settings.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a non-domain network as you say, do the following:

1) Create a a new local account on the server with the same name as your workstation account name.
2) Assign the same password as yours to the new account on the server
3) Give at least MODIFY NTFS access to the folder you want to have access to
4) Make sure that the share's permissions are set to FULL CONTROL

Comment: Thanks. But can I do this without creating new accounts neither on server nor on my workstation? Just using existing ones?